# Passing radio value with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I have a form that has a set of radio buttons (3 choices), and I am using angular and the ng-repeat directive to populate the html:

```
<div ng-repeat="fruit in fruitbasket">
  <input type="radio" name="fruit" data-ng-model="fruit.isSelected">{{fruit.id}}
</div>
```

the inside of the controller for the fruit basket looks like this:

```
$scope.fruitbasket = [{isSelected: false, id: "Orange", value: "1"}, {isSelected: true, id: "Pear", value: "2"}, {isSelected: false, id: "Apple", value: "3"}]
```

The choices in the view are Orange, Pear, and Apple, but after one is selected I want to pass the numeric "value"

Not sure how to do this in angular, I have tried several things, but non successful.  Each time the passed value shows as `nil`

How does a connected element of an object get passed from a radio button in Angularjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

1. isSelected is not needed. The fruitbasket is not part of your model, only the selected fruit is.

   ```
   $scope.fruitbasket = [
       {id: "Orange", value: "1"},
       {id: "Pear", value: "2"},
       {id: "Apple", value: "3"}
   ];

   $scope.model={selectedFruit:2};
   ```
2. Assign the value (**fruit.value**) to each option and bind it to your model (**model.selectedFruit**)

   ```
   <input value="{{fruit.value}}" data-ng-model="model.selectedFruit" type="radio" name="fruit" > {{fruit.id}}
   ```

Check out [this working plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/6E1YDfpcQ67qHTizc11v?p=preview).

Comment: @joakimbi In the scope of the model, why is selectedFruit set to 2?

Comment: I did it because in your question you had `isSelected: true` on "Pear". If you don't want to pre select an item you can just set `$scope.model={};`

Comment: @joakimbi when is use $scope.model={}; the object that gets passed is {"selectedFruit"=>"2"} but what I really need passed is just "2"... any thoughts?

Comment: Could you show me how you send the data - do you use $http, a $resource or something else?

Comment: @joakimbi through a fruits service, that uses $resource

Comment: Well, if you have a $resource named Fruits I guess `Fruits.save($scope.model.selectedFruit ...` would POST `2` to the $resource url, but I'd be surprised if that is what you really want...